# How to create custom URL structure using pages with Gridsome(Vue.js)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url, routes, gridsome

Thanks for helping people.

I am trying to create a URL pattern like: courses>levels>beginner>1

I did [this](https://gridsome.org/docs/pages/) and could create the first sub-folder but it doesn't keep on going.

> src/pages/Index.vue becomes / (The frontpage)
>
> src/pages/AboutUs.vue becomes /about-us/
>
> src/pages/about/Vision.vue becomes /about/vision/
>
> src/pages/blog/Index.vue becomes /blog/

I want to do src/pages/courses/levels ...

I put Index.vue too. I also tried nuxt.js way of adding "_id". How can I achieve this?